# Compute $e^{ t( 2 x \frac{d}{dx} + 3 y \frac{d}{dy})} f(x,y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, lie-groups

I was reading a rather old textbook on Lie groups.  He gave us an infinitesimal transformation:

$$   L =  2 x \frac{d}{dx} + 3 y \frac{d}{dy}    $$

And he asked what was the global transformation generated by this.

$$e^{ t( 2 x \frac{d}{dx} + 3 y \frac{d}{dy})} f(x,y)= \text{?} $$

I could do a much easier one:

$$e^{ t \frac{d}{dx} } f(x)= f(x) + t f'(x) + (t^2/2)f''(x) +\dots= f(x+t)$$
This is just Taylor's theorem.

Comment: If we let $X = x \partial_x$ and $Y = y \partial_y$ then $[X, Y] = 0$ so by [the Zassenhaus formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#The_Zassenhaus_formula) $e^{t(2X+3Y)} = e^{2tX} e^{3tY}$. Thus a good start is to calculate $e^{sX}$ and $e^{sY}$ (the latter is practically the same as the former).

Comment: Also note that $x^n$ is an eigenfunction to $X$. Use this to find the eigenvalues of $e^{sX}$. Then find what $e^{sX}$ does to an analytic function $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n x^n$.